# The $n$th derivative of $g$ equals this function. What is $g$?

Tags: integration, derivatives

I hope to find the $g(x)$ where, for all $n\ge0\in\mathbb{Z}$ and some $s$,
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}g(x)=\frac{n!}{n+2}\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{(k^s-x)^{n+2}}}$$

In a similar example we can say that
$$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{(k^s-x)^2}}=(n+1)!\sum_{k=1}^\infty{\frac{1}{(k^s-x)^{n+2}}}$$

but what is $g(x)$ not in terms of $n$? So far the solution has evaded all my efforts.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $s > 1$, just letting $n=0$ in the formula of the $n$-th derivative gives us

$$g(x) = \frac 1 2 \sum _{k \ge 1} \frac 1 {(k^s - x)^2} : \Bbb R \setminus \{ k^s \mid k \in \Bbb N \setminus \{0\} \} \to \Bbb R$$

and you shouldn't hope for a closed formula because already for $x=0$ this gives

$$g(0) = \frac 1 2 \sum _{k \ge 1} \frac 1 {k^{2s}} = \frac 1 2 \zeta (2s)$$

which is just a fancy name for something that we don't know. For $x \ne 0$ things are clearly uglier.